# Does the Improper integral $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln x}$ converge or diverge and how do you show it?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

So I know $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ is negative on the interval $(0,1)$ and you will maybe have to break the integral up into $(\int_{0^+}^{1/2} \frac{1}{\ln x}+\int_{1/2}^{1^-}\frac{1}{\ln x}$ since $\frac{1}{\ln x}$ is not defined at $0$ and $1$. I also know that $\int_0^1\ln x= \int_0^\infty-e^{-x}$ if that helps in anyway. How can i prove it converges or diverges??

I have tried to use the basic comparison method and limit comparison method with no success :(

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know that unicodes are not necessary for formatting math formulas. For some basic information about writing math at this site see [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Do you want to prove that $\int 1/\ln(x) $ between 0 and 1 is converge ?

Comment: Change variables: write $x=\exp(-t)$ so $\log x = -t$ and $dx=-\exp(-t)\,dt$ and so on, and look hard at the new integral.

Comment: I need to prove that ∫1/lnx from 0 to 1 is either converging or diverging @Youem

Comment: Is diverging look at the answer of @SimplyBeautifulArt

Comment: $\ln\left(\,{x}\,\right) \sim x - 1$ as $x \to 1^{-}$. So, it $\textit{diverges}$ logarithmically at the upper limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple approach involves noticing that

$$a<x<1\implies(1-x)\ln(a)<\ln(x)<x-1$$

This follows from the simple fact that $\ln(x)$ is concave, and thus, it is bounded above by it's tangent line (which is $x-1$) and bounded below by it's secant line (which is $(1-x)\ln(a)$).

Thus, since $\ln(1/2)=-\ln(2)$,

$$\frac12<b<1\implies\int_{1/2}^b\frac1{x-1}~\mathrm dx<\int_{1/2}^b\frac1{\ln(x)}~\mathrm dx<\frac1{\ln(2)}\int_{1/2}^b\frac1{x-1}~\mathrm dx$$

And as $b\to1^-$, all three integrals diverge.

Comment: would this same example also work for 0+ to 1/2? thank you so much by the way

Comment: @theshah Not quite, since the integral converges in that region.  It's easy enough to show that: $$0<x<a<1\implies\frac1{\ln(a)}<\frac1{\ln(x)}<0$$And so the integral from $0^+$ to $1/2$ exists and lies in $\left(-\frac1{2\ln(2)},0\right)$

Comment: i am trying to use the basic comparison theorem to prove these are converging/diverging but that theorem only allows that functions must be nonnegative. But i have heard that if the absolute value of a function converges/diverges then the original function converges/diverges. Also what would i say about the entire integral from 0 to 1 if the first part converges and the second part diverges?

Comment: @theshah The comparison test may be applied by factoring a $-1$ out the integral and appropriately multiplying all inequalities by $-1$.  And yes, by definition, if you split the integral over multiple parts, all parts must converge for the original to converge.

Answer (score 1):

Just integrate by parts,

$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac1{\ln (x)}dx = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \left.\frac{x}{ \ln (x)}\right|^{1-\epsilon}_{0+\epsilon} + \int_0^1 \frac{x}{ \ln^2 (x)}dx~,$$

notice that the limit diverges and the other integral is a positive, then the improper integral diverges to infinity. You should do a limit convergence test with $x/\ln^2 x$ to make sure that the integral above diverges

Answer (score 0):

By $x=1-y$ we have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln x}=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\ln (1-y)}dy=\int_0^\frac12 \frac{1}{\ln (1-y)}dy+\int_\frac12^1 \frac{1}{\ln (1-y)}dy$$

and since $\lim_{y\to 1^-} \frac{1}{\ln (1-y)}=0$ all boils down in the first one which diverges by limit comparison test with $\int_0^\frac12 \frac1y dy$

$$\lim_{y\to 0^+} \frac{\frac{1}{\ln (1-y)}}{\frac1y}=\lim_{y\to 0^+} \frac{y}{\ln (1-y)}=1$$

Comment: why can you use the limit comparison test ? ln(x) in this segment is negative